# have element change appreance with only javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html

attempting to have my webpage be a bit more dynamic by having the background change on some elements when a checkbox is clicked. I am trying to do this via class change and a CSS sheet. I have the following which is kicking out an error that my onclick function ins not defined (in IE9). More importantly will the webpage update if I only change the class of the object which would have a different class in the CSS file. Whats a better alternative if this does not work?

my elemenet and function

***UPDATE*** 
I made updates to both my HTML and CSS file as suggested by many. I am still getting no change in my webpage but the console is claiming that my function called from the onclick event is not defined which is a bit odd since it is. Also does this type for scripting belong in the HTML or should I pull it out and put in a seperate file. I figured since it was creating elements it belongs in the main html. Is there a cleaner more compact way of accomplishing this and not making my home screen html huge?

```
<tr class= 'tr.notchosen'><td><input type='checkbox' onclick='handleClick(this.id)'/></td></tr> 

function handleClick(cb) {

     var currentColumn = cb.parentNode
     var currentRow = currentColumn.parentNode
     if (currentRow.className === "chosen")
     {
     currentRow.className = "notchosen";
     }
     else
     {
     currentRow.className = "chosen";
     }
    }
```

and my css file is the following

```
tr.chosen
{
background-color:rgba(255,223,0,0.75);
}
tr.notchosen
{
background-color:rgba(255,223,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Classnames aren't selectors.

Comment: your css is for a tr tag and choosen class, but your js is for the 'tr.choosen' class.

Comment: @SLaks: huh? .myclass should select all myclass elements, should it not?

Comment: @dandavis: Yes, but he isn't using that classname.

Comment: @SLaks: gotcha, thats what i was trying to convey...

Comment: Periods are illegal characters in CSS class names. Change `<tr class= 'tr.notchosen'>` to `<tr class= 'notchosen'>`. You'll also need to update the `if()` statement and `currentRow.className`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments I have updated the code. Still have an issue thouhg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here. First, your css selector is not quite right. In fact, I would suggest making the class name just "chosen" or "not chosen" and then selecting tr elements with that class.

```
<tr class='notchosen'>
```

And then you can target it from css (which was probably the original intention)

```
tr.notchosen
{
 background-color:rgba(255,223,0,0);
}
```

Further, although I would not suggest using inline javascript, using your example, you should pass `this` if you want to work with the element and not `this.id` which would pass a string.

```
onclick='handleClick(this)'
```

The last part would be to sync up your javascript with the class name change

```
if (currentRow.className == "chosen")
{
 currentRow.className = "notchosen";
}
else
{
 currentRow.className = "chosen";
}
```

Comment: And prefer using === when comparing to "chosen"

Comment: Many thanks I have made the updates as suggested though I am getting a SCRIPT5009: 'handleClick' is undefined in the console window for IE9. Also is there a better way to get the parent of a parentnode then what I am doing now with having to declare a variable just to get the parent of that variable.